# Import .eml files in outook 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

I bought a new laptop a few days ago and installed office 2013, using outlook 2013 as my email client. I have a folder saved on my hard drive that has all my emails in .eml file format. The folder contains all my emails from previous version of windows live mail and now I want this folder to be imported into outlook 2013. Though I like outlook 2013 very much but import function in outlook 2013 is a complicated one. In import function the option to import .eml files does not exists, so is there any other way to import that folder into outlook 2013.

Comment: With older versions of Outlook, I've successfully used simple `drag n drop`.. Is it still functioning.?

Comment: As per @week's suggestion, open Outlook and dock it to side of screen. Open Windows Explorer (where the directory of your eml file is) and dock to other side of screen. Highlight all .eml files and drag them into Outlook.

Comment: use .eml to .pst converter and import .pst file into outlook 2013.

Answer (score 7):

I can recommend **free** [Import Messages from EML Format](http://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookMessagesImportEML) utility (I'm one of its developers) because it can retain original folder structure if it exists (drag'n'drop can not).

Comment: Sure. 100% malware free and all signed with trusted Symantec/VeriSign certificate.

Comment: Actually I haven't succeed to export all eml files I want from gmail so I can't use your program :( Have you a program that exports Gmail Emails ?

Comment: Of course it exports any type of accounts supported by Outlook. Make sure to have your account configured in Outlook. And the mentioned tool IMPORTS eml files (another tool available for exporting EML files).

Comment: You saved my day!

Answer (score -1):

1. Open Outlook and dock it to side of screen.
2. Open Windows Explorer (where the directory of your eml file is) and dock to other side of screen.
3. **Highlight all .eml files and drag them into Outlook.**

Comment: When I did this, it tried to create a new email message with the selected files as attachments. This was in Outlook 2013.

Comment: `it tried to create a new email message with the selected files as attachments` the same way it behaves now, nothing changed during last 8 years